# How To Use Key Value in Stored Array in New Select Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working in PHP and MySQL to create and list a membership directory.  I have three tables - company, contact and branch. Companies have Contact people, and some but not all companies have Branches, which also have Contact people.  I am using LEFT JOIN in my first query to connect the contact people to their respective company, and loading the results into an array, which works using the following code:

```
// Retrieve all the data from the "company" table
$query = "SELECT * FROM company LEFT JOIN contact ON company.company_id = contact.company_id WHERE comp_county = 'BERNALILLO' ORDER BY company.comp_name, contact.cont_rank"; 

$result = mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());

// Build the $company_array
$company_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $company_array[] = $row;
}
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to run a second query, which needs to select from my branch table all branches whose company_id match the company_id stored in my above array: $company_array.  I then want to store the results of the second query into a second array called $branch_array.  I have tried this:

```
// Retrieve all the matching data from the "branch" table
foreach($company_array as $row) {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM branch LEFT JOIN contact ON branch.branch_id = contact.branch_id WHERE branch.company_id = '".$row['company_id']."' ORDER BY branch.br_name, contact.cont_rank";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2)
or die(mysql_error());
}
// Build the $branch_array
$branch_array = array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $branch_array[] = $row2;
}
```

But this does not seem to work... Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?  The query needs to run so that it checks each different company_id in my $company_array for a match in the branch table - hopefully the question makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your while should be inside your foreach statement so that your `$branch_array` can be filled with results of all `company_id` values, not only the last one :

```
foreach($company_array as $row) {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM branch LEFT JOIN contact ON branch.branch_id = contact.branch_id WHERE branch.company_id = '".$row['company_id']."' ORDER BY branch.br_name, contact.cont_rank";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2)
or die(mysql_error());

// Build the $branch_array
    $branch_array = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $branch_array[] = $row2;
    }
}
```